# jQuery.slides() is not working

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

I'm using the [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) jQuery plugin and calling

```
jQuery.slides();
```

However, this is not working correctly. Instead, the images are just all being displayed (as you would expect without the plugin).

Why isn't this working and how can I get this to work?

I'm certain the javascript is being ran as I have placed `alert()` above and below my slides() statement to test.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">
        <div>
            <img src="Images/sample_banner.png" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/984x111" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/984x111/ff0000" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="left_arrow"><a href="#"><img src="Images/left_arrow.png" alt="left arrow control" /></a></div>
 <div class="right_arrow"><a href="#"><img src="Images/right_arrow.png" alt="right arrow control" /></a></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.banner
{
    width:984px;
    border-left:solid 7px #FFFFFF;
    border-right: solid 7px #FFFFFF;    
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}

    .banner .slides
    {
    }
        .banner .slides .slides_container {
            width:984px;
            height:111px;
        }
            .banner .slides .slides_container div
            {
                width:984px;
                height:111px;
                display:block;
            }


.left_arrow
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:25px;
    left:0px;
    top:38px;

}

.right_arrow
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    width:25px;
    left:960px;
    top:38px;
}
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slides').slides({
           next: 'right_arrow'
           , prev: 'left_arrow'
           , pagination: false
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your question is basically solved. Then there were some other problems with the layout.

1. How can **.banner .slides** apply, if there is no `<div class="banner" />` ?
2. Arrow placements were wrong and their css was not optimal
3. You don't need to set the width or height on so many places
4. Pagination was still appearing, though you didn't want it
5. Weird issue with arrows and z-index

And there were more of small issues, that I fixed, made the code optimal and dry.

**My example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/RSncf/1/**

Comment: 1. Sorry I must have missed that tag out when copying my markup

Comment: @PieterDeBie since 2011 alot has changed. So Slides JS has gone trough changes and there for the resource is not available.

Comment: Whoops sorry, should have looked at the date.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript you are targeting an id **#slides** and in your markup your containing div element has a class declaration - so change your markup to <div id="slides"> and give that a whirl.

Comment: Woops sorry for wasting your time, that was a typo! I've edited my question now

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I did this same thing.

It's because the function isn't .slides it's .slidesjs

At least, that's what fixed it for me.